# estou fazendo um post para cadastrar anuncios mas ele nao acha o user_id

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-request

Eu estou criando um post em que eu possa cadastrar e salvar anúncios do meu aplicativo para minha api. 
Quando eu clico em cadastrar ele retorna o erro got 422 porem se eu coloco o user id manualmente e permanente (user_id = @"1") ele funciona normalmente porem ele com este codigo: ***newAd.user_id = [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] _id];***, ele nao funciona e retorna o erro.

este é o meu WebService:

```
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "Ads.h"

static NSString *kServerURL = @"http://localhost:3000";

@interface JVWebService ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) RKObjectManager *restKitObjectManager;

@end

#define kSuccessStatusCode RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)

@implementation JVWebService

+ (instancetype)sharedService {
    static JVWebService *sharedService = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedService = [[self alloc] init];

        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
        sharedService.restKitObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServerURL]];
        [sharedService.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] email]
                                                                                 password:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] password]];
    });
    return sharedService;
}

#pragma mark - User

- (void)getUserForEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_in.json";

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    User *user = [User new];
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey:@"authencity_token"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:password];
    [self.restKitObjectManager postObject:user path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                                                     RKMappingResult *result){
        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;
        user.password = password;
        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:user];

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setLoggedViaFacebook:NO];

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    }

- (void)createUser:(User *)user{
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {}];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)updateUser:(User *)user withProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authencity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPATCH path:path parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage)
//                                            name:@"user[avatar]"
//                                        fileName:@"profileImage.jpg"
//                                        mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:(User *) result.array.firstObject];
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:result.firstObject];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)logout {
    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_out.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager deleteObject:[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] logout];



        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (void)sendResetPasswordInstructionsToEmail:(NSString *)email {
    NSString *path = @"/send_lost_password.json";

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email};

    [self.restKitObjectManager getObject:nil path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
}




- (void)postAd:(Ads *)ad {
    NSString *path = @"/ads.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:Ads.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.adAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postAdAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:Ads.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];

    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:ad method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//        NSArray *photosArray = ad.photos[0];
//        for(int i = 0; i < photosArray.count; i++) {
//            
//            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ad[photos_attributes][%i][picture]", i];
//            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo%i.jpg", i];
//            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photosArray[i])
//                                        name:name
//                                    fileName:fileName
//                                    mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
//        }
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

                                                                                               } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
                                                                                               }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (NSDictionary *)adAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"local",
             @"description" : @"especification",
             @"categories" : @"categories",
             @"photos" : @"photos",
             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postAdAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"local",
             @"especification" : @"description",
             @"categories" : @"category_ids",
             @"user_id" : @"user_id",
             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)userAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"avatar" : @"profileImageUrl",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"contact_pref" : @"communicationPreference",
             @"products_alerts" : @"productsAlerts"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postUserAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"password" : @"password_confirmation",
             @"communicationPreference" : @"contact_pref"
             };
}
@end
```

este é o meu AppDelegate onde eu coloco meu CurrentUser:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BaseViewController.h"

#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"

#import "NSUserDefaults+RMSaveCustomObject.h"
#import "NSObject+RMArchivable.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (instancetype)sharedDelegate {
    static AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    });
    return sharedDelegate;
}



- (void) login:(User *)user {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] rm_setCustomObject:user forKey:@"currentUser"];

}

- (void) logout {
    self.currentUser = nil;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"currentUser"];
}

- (User *) user {
    if(!self.currentUser) {
        self.currentUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] rm_customObjectForKey:@"currentUser"];
    }
    return self.currentUser;
}

// During the Facebook login flow, your app passes control to the Facebook iOS app or Facebook in a mobile browser.
// After authentication, your app will be called back with the session information.

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "br.com.JaVendi" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"JaVendi" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"JaVendi.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

@end
```

e agora a view onde eu cadastro um anuncio:

```
#import "NewAdViewController.h"
#import "Ads.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface NewAdViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewAdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}



//iguala os valores das strings com os campos de textos
- (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender {


    if (self.titleField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa dar um nome ao seu anúncio." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.priceField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"você precisa dar um preço ao seu anúncio" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.localField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Qual o local do anúncio?" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.descriptionField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Descreva seu anúncio" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else {
            Ads *newAd = [Ads new];
            newAd.title = self.titleField.text;
            newAd.price = self.priceField.text;
            newAd.local = self.localField.text;
            newAd.especification = self.descriptionField.text;
            newAd.categories = nil;
            newAd.user_id = [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] _id];
            newAd.latitude = nil;
            newAd.longitude = nil;
            newAd.photos = nil;

            [[JVWebService sharedService] setServiceDelegate:self];
            [[JVWebService sharedService] postAd:newAd];

        }
    }

//se o cadastro tiver sucesso
- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {

    [JVUtils showMessage:@"Anuncio cadastrado =D" withTitle:@"hadoukeeeen !"];

    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

//se o cadastro falhar

- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [JVUtils showMessage:error.localizedDescription withTitle:@"Errohue"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Você verificou se `Ads.user_id` e `[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] _id]` são ambos do tipo NSString?